# Lifting a using statement outside of function definition

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, using

The following is valid c++:

```
template <typename BAR, int BAZ>
Foo<BAR, BAZ> & operator -= ( Foo<BAR, BAZ> & left, Foo<BAR, BAZ> const right )
{
    using reference = Foo<BAR, BAZ> &;
    using const_value = Foo<BAR, BAZ> const;
    ...
    return left;
}
```

But `Foo<BAR, BAZ>` could actually be a pretty long identifier, and I wish to somehow have the using statements apply to the function definition in addition to the the contents, if for nothing but aesthetics and clarity.  Basically, is it possible to write something similar to the following as a free standing function?

```
template <typename BAR, int BAZ>
... // using/typedef statements that define 'reference' and 'const_value',
... // but only defines them for this function
reference operator -= ( reference left, const_value right )
{
    ...
    return left;
}
```

Comment: You could use a type function (C++98) or return type deduction (C++14). You can also hide those using-statements in some namespaces, define your function there and provide a wrapper outside using C++11-style return type "deduction" via `decltype`.

Comment: "Foo<BAR, BAZ> could actually be a pretty long identifier" but you could make it shorter (and more understandable) by typedeffing BAR and BAZ.

Comment: @dyp Nice ideas, but wouldn't the arguments of the function wrapper outside the namespace also need to be declared using Foo<BAR, BAZ>?

Comment: Ah, I didn't examine your example carefully enough. You cannot get rid of the function parameter types easily with this technique. Type functions could still work fine.

Comment: #define and #undef? ;)

Answer (score 0):

SFINAE.

First, define a type discrimination metafunction (type -> bool)

```
template<class> struct is_Foo : std::false_type {};
template<class X, class Y> struct is_Foo<Foo<X,Y>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then utilize it with `std::enable_if_t<.....>` (or `typename std::enable_if<.....>::type` in pre-C++14)

First way is to add a dummy template parameter, derived from T.
In success it becomes just void, in failure - SFINAE makes the compiler to skip this overloading.

```
template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<is_Foo<T>::value>>
T& operator -= (T& src, const T& dst)
{
    .....
    return src;
}
```

Second way is more convinient, attempting to derive the result type.
In success it should be exactly what we must return.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<is_Foo<T>::value, T&> operator -= (T& src, const T& dst)
{
    .....
    return src;
}
```

The benefit of first way is to write `auto` (or `auto&`) instead of explicit return type, and let the compiler to deduce it from return value.

If you want to know parameters of the template Foo, just extend the metafunction.

```
template<class> struct traits_of_Foo;  // undefined for non-Foo types

template<class X, class Y> struct traits_of_Foo<Foo<X,Y>>
{
    using Param1 = X;
    using Param2 = Y;
};
```